# PIXI BitmapText bug ("can't read property 'size' of undefined")

Tags: text, pixi.js

I can't even instantiate a `BitmapText` object from either `pixi.js` or `pixi.dev.js` without encountering the error

```
pixi.dev.js:3688 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined
```

My implementation is their trivial [example](http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/docs/classes/BitmapText.html)

```
text = new PIXI.BitmapText('test', {font:'Arial'});
```

I've traced the error exactly to the attempted instantiation above. 
Here is the relevant snippet from the `pixi.dev.js` source code (with the error occurring on the last line).

```
PIXI.BitmapText.prototype.updateText = function()
{
    var data = PIXI.BitmapText.fonts[this.fontName];
    var pos = new PIXI.Point();
    var prevCharCode = null;
    var chars = [];
    var maxLineWidth = 0;
    var lineWidths = [];
    var line = 0;
    var scale = this.fontSize / data.size;
    ...
```

Is this a bug in the library, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BitmapText requires you to load a font first. You can create a font using the BMFont software from angelcode: http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/

When you export your font from BMFont, you end up with a png image that looks like a Texture Atlas, plus an xml file.
You can then load your BitmapFont like this:

```
var loader = new PIXI.AssetLoader(["MyBitmapFont.xml"]);
loader.onComplete = function()
{
    stage.addChild( new PIXI.BitmapText("SomeText", { font: "35px MyBitmapFont", align: "left"}));
};
loader.load();
```

PIXI Example 10 is a more complete example:
https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/tree/master/examples/example%2010%20-%20Text

You can use the example font, "desyrel" to try it out for yourself.